# javascript getElementsByClassName value error

Tags: javascript, class, get

I've got a little function in javascript popUp and i am wondering if getElementByClassName function returns an array of all elements with that class than why when i'm alerting it says object Html input element despite what i have inside my form number fields (blank space or some number).So how do i get values from that array.

```
 var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('num');

function popUp(){
    for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
        alert(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id = "matrix">

<input type = "number" class = "num" />
<input type = "number" class = "num" />

<input type = "number" class = "num" />
<input type = "number" class = "num" />

<input type = "button" value = "count" id = "count" onclick = "popUp()"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: It returns an array-like object (actually an HTMLCollection) of _elements_ - not _values_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .value

like

```
alert(arr[i].value);
```

If you need to be compatible with IE8-, you shouldn't use

```
type = "number"
```

It's HTML5 and not supported by IE8-.
Use type="text" instead.

Comment: Yes there is an input type "number"

Comment: @Tomer Arazy: Yes I just saw. It's new in HTML5.

Comment: If jQuery can drop support for IE8 I think that someone who's a beginner can drop support for IE8...

Comment: @Tomer Arazy: jQuery develops 2.0 and 1.9.1 in parallel. 2.0 is basically 1.9.1 with support for IE8 removed, to speed it up. For now, you can use 1.9.1. IE8 is only going to disappear at the end of support for windows XP in 2014. At my company, we thought we could drop support for IE8, but what an error that was - then the complaints about blank/black pages started coming in (especially at product demos at the clients)... IE8 is here to stay for a little longer, but yes, a beginner for private use could ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of DOM elements so `arr[i]` gets you the DOM element, not what's in the element.  If you want a property from that DOM element like the `value` of an `input` tag, then you have to reference the property you want such as `.value`:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('num');

function popUp(){
    for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
        alert(arr[i].value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName will return a list of all matching html elements. By calling alert(arr[i]), you are telling the client to show the element, and not its value, which is why the alert message tells you that its an html input. To show the element's value, use the following

```
alert(arr[i].value);
```